# material-ui createMuiTheme palette type dark does not change textcolor to light

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

[image: Screenshot]

I have set the palette type: dark in createMuiTheme and it changes the background color to dark, which is good. But the text color stays black. Shouldn't it adapt a lighter color?

CodeSandbox link : https://codesandbox.io/s/j22rvq4w2v

```
import React from 'react'; 
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { MuiThemeProvider, createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import CssBaseline from '@material-ui/core/CssBaseline';
import App from './App';

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    type: 'dark',
  },
});

ReactDOM.render(

<MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
    <React.Fragment>
        <CssBaseline />
            <App/>
    </React.Fragment>
</MuiThemeProvider>,
     document.getElementById('app'));
```

The app component just contains an AppBar and simple text.

***Update***: The version of material-ui I have, which I mentioned earlier as v1 is incorrect. Sorry about misinformationtion and it is 3.10.10

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are simply misinterpreting what *CssBaseline* is for. That component is some kind of CSS resetter, and doesn’t add any visual style — only layout, box-sizing stuff.

What you really want is the [*Typography* component](https://material-ui.com/style/typography/).

See the [updated and working CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/jp8yn0nr39).

Comment: Did this solve your issue? If so, you can accept it :)

Comment: In your sandbox you configure primary and secondary palettes as well. I question why if you don't use them afterwards? This is confusing and it's still not clear how to configure light and dark theme types.

Comment: @Onkeltem the CodeSandbox I linked is a fork of the original one and inherits al code from it. I reduced my changes to the bare minimum to help the original poster. Also this issue is not about Dark/Light palettes, but how to use typography components.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the proper color then:

```js
import React from "react";
import { MuiThemeProvider, createMuiTheme } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import blueGrey from "@material-ui/core/colors/blueGrey";
import lightGreen from "@material-ui/core/colors/lightGreen";
import Reset from "@material-ui/core/CssBaseline";

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      light: lightGreen[300],
      main: lightGreen[500],
      dark: lightGreen[700]
    },
    secondary: {
      light: blueGrey[300],
      main: blueGrey[500],
      dark: blueGrey[700]
    }
  }
});
```

PD: maybe update the material-u v.3 it`s out
Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks @FizzVR, for helping, I tried that snippet with and without property type:dark. That doesn't seem to help.

Answer (score 0):

Just upgrade `@material-ui/core` to **v3.0.1**. It should work like a charm.

Comment: the current version is 3.10.10. That doesn't seem to help. I am missing something basic Hoping to find that out soon :)